# Updating text within a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I have been trying to update some `<label>` elements within a `x-kendo-template` with some text based on a drop down selection. This template is used when exporting a grid to PDF.

**Grid Initialisation**

```
var grid = $("#reportGrid").kendoGrid({                        
    height: "auto",
    pdf: {            
        template: kendo.template($("#page-template").html()),
        ... other options for pdf export
    },        
    ... other options for the grid
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="page-template">
    <div>Catalogue Number: <span id="catalogueNumber_Report" data-bind="text: CatalogueNumber"></span></div>
    <div>Lot Number: #: LotNumber #</div>
    <div>Size: ${Size}</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 25%;">Expiry: <label id="expiryDateLabel_Report"></label></div>    
</script>
```

**Javascript function to update text**

```
function assignLotDetailLabels(selectedItem) {    
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        LotNumber: selectedItem.LotNumber,
        CatalogueNumber: selectedItem.CatalogueNumber,
        Size: selectedItem.Size
    });
    kendo.bind($("#page-template"), viewModel);
    $('#expiryLabel_Report').text(selectedItem.ExpiryDate);
}
```

None of the above has worked for me so far (none of the labels are populated with the associated fields). Is there a different way I should be doing this?

**EDIT**

Changing the `HTML` to access the `data` attributes returns `undefined` instead of just being empty if this is any indication to what I am missing?

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="page-template">
    <div>Catalogue Number: #: data.CatalogueNumber #</div>
    <div>Lot Number: #: data.LotNumber #</div>
    <div>Size: #: data.Size #</div>
    <div>Expiry: #: data.ExpiryDate #</div> 
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        LotNumber: selectedLot.LotNumber,
        CatalogueNumber: selectedLot.CatalogueNumber,
        Size: selectedLot.Size
    });
    kendo.bind($("#page-template"), viewModel);
```

Additionally, is there a way to debug HTML to view what `data` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't too far away with option 2 (`#: LotNumber #`) however I hadn't referenced the Javascript `viewModel` variable. Additionally, the `viewModel` variable needs global scope with default values and the attributes within should be `set()` as and when required.

**Example**

HTML Template:

```
<div>Lot Number: #: viewModel.LotNumber #</div>
```

viewModel declared as a global variable:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    LotNumber: 0,
    CatalogueNumber: 0,
    Size: "S",
    ExpiryDate: new Date()
});
```

Set attribute of viewModel in `assignLotDetailLabels`:

```
function assignLotDetailLabels(selectedItem) {   
    viewModel.set("LotNumber", selectedItem.LotNumber);
    // all the rest of the properties to set    
}
```

And last but not least, it is possible to view contents of the `viewModel` variable by using console output inside the template `# console.log(viewModel) #`